# Is it possibile to write on a file put into an apk?

Tags: android

Is it possibile to write on a file (for instance  a .txt) put into an apk?
When a user close my app, i'd like to write something on a file and then read it when my app is re-opened.

Comment: You cannot change the APK (and this would require resigning it and the user does not have your singing information). On the other hand, it is not problem to store a file in the internal memory of SD card.

Comment: Yes you can. The file must be written in sdcard. [Check this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6847890/1821326

Comment: you can use Shared Preference or database.

Answer (score 0):

You should write into shared preferences or create a file in the app-private /data folder. If you have other stuff at compile time that should be in that file too, store it to a resource and write that to the new file in /data at first start.

Answer (score 0):

Thank everybody for your help.
Maybe the best way to do what i want to do was suggested by @Priya.

I used Preferences.

But i'm still wondering if it's suitable and appropriate for what i want to do. I want to keep track of the points that users earn while playing my game; when users re-open my app, i have to show all the points they earned since they installed my app. I'm just wondering if Preferences are suitable and appropriatefor this, or if i should use something else.

Anyway i post my code, it might help someone

```
public class managePreferences{
Context context;    

    managePreferences(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }


    public String readPreference(String fieldName, String defaultValue){    
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String value = prefs.getString(fieldName, defaultValue);
        return value ;
    }


    public void writePreference(String fieldName, String value){
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(fieldName, value);
        editor.commit();

    }

}
```